# Can bride give gifts to boy's family on wedding?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

Can a girl(bride) give gifts to boy's family with her own money during rukhsati(when bride leaves her home after marriage) because all the stuffs at that time the girl brings with her(that is not for her use) is dowry.so I have to know,will this gift be dowry?

Comment: What do you mean by dowry? From the woman to the man or from the man to the woman? If from the woman to the man, that is already non-Islamic. See here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/is-dowry-allowable-in-islam

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes into play here is intention. If you just want to give a gift with your heart then you can do it because here no one have an intention of giving or taking dowry. You can give gifts there is nothing wrong in it, just keep your intentions clean.